# Wiring Leviton Timer to Bath Fan and Switch to Light

Tags: electrical, switch, fan, receptacle, timer

I am a DIYer with a basic knowledge of electrical wiring.  I am having trouble wiring a bath fan to a timer and light to a switch.  I can get get power to one or the other, not both.  Here is the wiring configuration. Wires are coming into the wall box as shown, but not exiting.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Timer make/model: Leviton decora #LTB15

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: What country? Your wiring illustration needs more explanation? Is the fan and light a single unit? If not, what wires are in the light box? where does the yellow wire go? Are the red and green attached to the same terminal?

Comment: Sorry. Hit enter too soon.  I am in Canada.  Fan and light are separate units. Instructions for the time say Red/Yellow goes to the switch.  Can't seem to add another illustration, so wiring at light is as follows: White from bottom of wall box to connector and black to light.  White from light to connector and out to top left and right of wall box.  Black from bottom of wall box to top right of wall box.  And black from bottom of wall box to connector and red to top left of wall box.  Hope that makes sense.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for trying, but the physical positions are not helpful. Can you photograph the inside of each box? And the connection points for switch and timer? Place them on imgur.com and link from here. Also provide the model number for the timer.